# Bound on sum of the factors of product of two numbers

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory

Suppose $p,q$ be two natural number.If $t_1.t_2.\dots t_k=pq$ such that $\forall i\leq k$, $t_i\leq p$ or $t_i\leq q$ , then $\sum_{i=1}^{k}t_k\leq2p+2q-2$. I think this statement is true for $\forall k\leq p+q$. Is this statement is true?.

Assuming it is true, I have tried to prove it via a.m-g.m inequality but I could not.Give me some idea how to proceed it. If it is not true, then what is idea to get counter example.

Comment: Are you multiplying the $t_i$ together? Are the $t_i$ also natural numbers? In your sum formula should $t_k$ be $t_i$?